# Algebra filter error in moodle

Tags: moodle

I installed moodle 1.9.12 and now I want to use Algebra notation in content. I enable "TeX Notation" and "Algebra Notation" in administrator panel and also install mimetext and dvips and Imagemagic on the server. fortunately Tex Notation works fine but I got the following error for Algebra:

**sh: /var/www/html/moodle/filter/tex/mimetex.linux: not found**

**The shell command**

**"/var/www/html/moodle/filter/tex/mimetex.linux" -e "/var/www/moodledata/filter/algebra/de06d6c44d98ba4e42dffca988bf530b.gif" -- '\Large \frac{\sin\left(z\right)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}'
returned status = 127**

**File size of mimetex executable /var/www/html/moodle/filter/tex/mimetex.linux is 830675
The file permissions are: 100775**

**The md5 checksum of the file is 56bcc40de905ce92ebd7b083c76e019e
Image not found!**

Note: /var/www/html/moodle/filter/tex/mimetex.linux exists on the server and is executable!!!
What is the problem?? Any idea?????

Answer (score 0):

From what you have described, calling the general tex filter debug page works and does not show up the same error.

/filter/tex/texdebug.php works, but /filter/algebra/algebradebug.php does not.

If this is the case, perhaps you could check for an open_basedir, or safe_mode_exec_dir being set to include the current working directory, or otherwise restricting the execution of /var/www/html/moodle/filter/tex/mimetex.linux, while the current working directory is /var/www/html/moodle/filter/algebra.

You could look at this by visiting /admin/phpinfo.php at your site, and look carefully at the effective values of open_basedir, safe_mode and safe_mode_exec_dir.

You could also check the apache error log or add the following lines to the top of the algebra debug php file, and you might see some extra error messages:

```
$CFG->debug = 6143 ;
$CFG->debugdisplay= 1 ;
```

Hope that helps